# Application history and data usage history of a Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: windows-phone-8

Do we have any API for reading specific Application History ( like application installed date, version number, last updated on, etc.,) and also is there any way we can read the data usage of a specific WP8 application?

Comment: I don't know, if there's an API, but you can create such thing manually, if you can configure a server, that would receive statistics reports from user.

Comment: Did you mean a MDM Server?

Comment: I'm not a server programmer (that's why it's a comment, not an answer), but I think, there would be no difference for a mobile app. Just send statistics info via simple GET or POST requests using windows-phone HttpWebRequest or WebClient classes.

Comment: I understood what you said, Thank you Olter. On a Mobile Platform if we need to access a specific resource we need certain capabilities which are mostly restricted by these Mobile Platforms. Even in my case my application doesn't have enough capabilities for doing my job.

Comment: Well, you can save the data, you've mentioned, in isolatedStorage. Installed date and lastUpdated date can be saved using DateTime class. Version can be taken as a pre-saved Constant. If you want to check the time, your app is used by user, you can add DispatcherTimer. So, there are some ways to do this.